# If A is polynomial time reducible to B and B is in NP, then A is in NP

Tags: complexity-theory

*If $A\leq_p B$ and $B$ is in $NP$, is it true that $A$ is in $NP$*?

What about : *"if $A\leq_p B$ and $B$ is in $coNP$, then $A$ is in $coNP$"*?

Thanks in advance.

*I think both hold. If $B$ is in $NP$, then the yes-instances of $B$ can be verified in polynomial time. If $A \leq_p B$, I can "translate" an instance of $A$ to a instance of $B$. Then I can use the verification algorithm for $B$ to check the yes-instances of $A$. The same should be valid for the second affirmation. I'm not sure though.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think both hold too.

Co-NP version:some Problem A reduce to B,

if B is co-NP,$\overline{B}$ is in NP,and no-instance of B has some verify way and certificate bit. and A's no-instance can use it too.

So this A is complement of NP problem $\overline{A}$. this means complexity class of A is co-NP.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't understand why my post received 2 negative votes.

Comment: I don't know that.
I did up vote now.