# If $A\leq_P B$ and $B\in \text{NP}$, is $A\in \text{NP}$?

Tags: complexity-theory, np, polynomial-time

Let $A\leq_P B$ mean that the language $A$ is polynomial time reducible to $B$. It is a theorem that $A\leq_P B$ and $B\in \text{P}$ then $A\in \text{P}$.

My question is, if $A\leq_P B$ and $B\in \text{NP}$, is $A\in \text{NP}$?  What if $B$ is $\text{NP}$-complete?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If A is polynomial time reducible to B and B is in NP, then A is in NP](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/116861/if-a-is-polynomial-time-reducible-to-b-and-b-is-in-np-then-a-is-in-np)

Comment: The answer here is much better than the answer in that previous question, which I am not sure is true nor an answer. So this question should be the one people go to when they want to know the answer to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A \le_p B$ and $B \in \mathsf{NP}$ then $A \in \mathsf{NP}$.

A non-deterministic polynomial-time Turing machine that decides $A$ works as follows:

- Reduce the input instance $I_A$ of $A$ to an instance $I_B$ of $B$ using the polynomial-time reduction from $A$ to $B$.
- Simulate a nondeterministic polynomial-time Turing machine that decides $B$ on input $I_B$ (such a Turing machine exists since $B \in \mathsf{NP}$).

If $B$ is $\mathsf{NP}$-complete then it is still true that $A \in \mathsf{NP}$ since all $\mathsf{NP}$-complete are in $\mathsf{NP}$.
It is not necessarily true that $A$ is $\mathsf{NP}$-complete. As a counterexample choose $A = \emptyset$ and $B$ as the language of satisfiable SAT instances.
Notice that this does not require the assumption $\mathsf{P} \neq \mathsf{NP}$.